# macOS shortcut to toggle focus between side by side apps

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

During development / writing docs, I often find myself working on side-by-side apps on macOS.

- Since I use an ultra-wide external monitor, it is tedious to drag the pointer a significant distance all the way from one app to another for toggling focus between them.
- This feels especially tiresome and wasteful when one of those apps is an editor or IDE where I merely have to type -> something that can otherwise be accomplished purely via keyboard and doesn't require pointer input at all.

Is there a way to configure keyboard shortcut in macOS to help toggle focus between the side-by-side apps?

---

I'm on **MacOS Monterey v12.6 (21G115)**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- While I couldn't find an exact solution, as per [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7325621) on [discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/), `Move focus to active or next window` shortcut can be used here as a close-enough alternative

  - it can be configured by going to `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts` > `Keyboard` (on left pane) > `Move focus to active or next window` (5th item on list)
    [image]
- The catch is that technically this shortcut toggles b/w last 2 used apps, so you'll have to manually click on your side-by-side apps one-by-one to make them so; *otherwise it'll end up moving you across different (non side-by-side) apps*